# Technical Debt measured by GET api/measures/component VS GET api/issues/search

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube Version 7.2.1 and I have analyzed a Multi Module Maven Project.

In order to retrieve all the project's open issues I call `/api/issues/search?componentKeys=COMPONENT_KEY&ps=500&resolved=false`. Then I sum-up either the *effort* or the *debt* property in order to calculate the amount of debt of the open issues. I get a total of: **3704 mins**.

Later I realized that there is another endpoint namely: GET `api/measures/component` when I call it `/api/measures/component?component=COMPONENT_KEY&metricKeys=sqale_index` the amount of TD is different: **3449 mins**.

Which of the above numbers is correct and why is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

One possible difference could be the fact that in the second case you're limiting the metrics that are being considered by `metricKeys=sqaleIndex`.

Comment: I am not sure. According to [SonarQube's metric definitions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions), the sqale_index represents the effort to fix all maintainability issues. 

By calling the GET api/issues/search I believe that I retrieve all the open issues that have to be maintained.

Comment: Can you find maybe a small component in which you can manually `diff` the two sets of issues to see which are not counted? Might be useful for others to know too!